# Add XAML Style to xamarin From Blend

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cross-platform, xamarin.forms, blend

I've created a xaml style using Blend for Visual Studio, and I'm trying to add this style to my xamarin visual studio project, but it failed because it couldn't find the markup extension ThemeResource, is there a way to add this markup extension to my project?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blend is for WPF/Silverlight/UWP only, while Xamarin.Forms uses a slightly different XAML specs.

Microsoft/Xamarin should be able to let Blend support Xamarin.Forms in the future, but not now.